# Na string transp, era para aparecer todos os 4 nomes, porém, só aparece o último

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void texto();
void soma(int n1, int n2);
int soma2(int n1, int n2);
void tr(string tra[4]);

int main(){
    int res;
    string transp[4]=("carro","moto","barco","aviao");

    soma(15,5);
    res=soma2(175,25);

    cout << "valor de res: " << res << "\n";

    tr(transp);

         return 0;
}

void texto(){
    cout << "canal fessor bruno\n";
}

void soma(int n1, int n2){
    cout << "soma dos valores: " << n1+n2 << "\n";
}

int soma2(int n1, int n2){
    return n1+n2;
}

void tr(string tra[4]){
    for(int i=0; i<4; i++){
        cout << tra[i] << "\n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Do modo que você está inicializando o array o problema esta na utilização de parênteses no lugar de chaves.

Para esse caso a inicialização correta é:

```
string transp[4]={"carro","moto","barco","aviao"};
```

Pode ver o código funcionando [aqui](https://ideone.com/nAGFc2)

Ao utilizar os parênteses no lugar de chaves você está agrupando expressões e utilizando o operador comma (vírgula). Esse operador não é muito conhecido e ele serve para separar duas ou mais expressões (no teu caso uma string é uma expressão) e as expressões são avaliadas uma a uma da esquerda para a direita  e o valor da expressão inteira é o valor da última expressão na lista (no teu caso o valor da expressão é "avião", por isso ele coloca em todas as posições.)

Para mais detalhes você pode verificar:

[Built-in comma operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other#Built-in_comma_operator)

[Wikipedia comma operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator)